# Actionscript: Calling function with unknown arguments count

Tags: flash, actionscript

For example i have function declared in AS3.0 class:

```
private function log():void{
// working with arguments directly here
}
```

I'm calling:

```
log('some stuff',object,array,etc);
```

Then i'm calling:

```
log('ok');
```

Ofc FlashBuilder throws exception with: `type 1137: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected no more than 0`

How to do it?

**Update**

In javascript it's possible. But in AS not, isn't it's ECMA based? Why so strict...

**Update**

Ok nvm. Created like that atm: `log(m1:*=null,m2:*=null,m3:*=null,m4:*=null,m5:*=null):void{}`

Comment: why not send it as an array or object

Comment: solution as well, but kinda ugly :), each time to call log(['something'])

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `...` rest parameter for that:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#..._(rest)_parameter

Example from the docs:

```
function average(... args) : Number{
    var sum:Number = 0;
    for (var i:uint = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        sum += args[i];
    }
    return (sum / args.length);
}
```